# Reset a JavaScript Proxy object to default values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manage state for a small application that has to be written in pure JS. I thought a proxy object would be the right fit, as I need to update various elements on the page when certain properties are updated.

Suppose I have this code:

#### Shared Setup for all Examples

```js
const defaults = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

const state = { ...defaults };
```

#### Body of Code

```js
const proxy = new Proxy(state, {
}); 

proxy.foo = 'baz'
```

We have a bare proxy that's not doing anything. But I want to implement a function or a trap that can reset all of the values of the proxied object back to the original defaults.

I'm imagining being able to call something like `proxy.reset()`.

I've tried something like this, but it just doesn't seem to update the object:

```js
const proxy = new Proxy(state, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if(prop == 'reset') {
      target = { ...defaults }
    }
  }
}); 

proxy.foo = 'baz'
proxy.reset
```

Any ideas? Do I need to use some other kind of object at the beginning? I'm trying to avoid simply setting the values manually, as the default object is likely to change as I develop. It feels like there should be an elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Would tell you are loosing a "pointer" setting target - you can set properties, but not change object by this.

```js
const defaults = {
    foo: 'bar'
};

const state = { ...defaults };

const proxy = new Proxy(state, {
    get (target, prop) {
        if (prop === 'reset') {
            Object.assign(target, defaults);
            /*for (var i in defaults) {
                target[i] = defaults[i];
            }*/
        }
        if (prop === 'get') {
            return target;
        }
    }
});

proxy.foo = 'baz';
console.log(proxy.get);
proxy.reset;
console.log(proxy.get);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to roll my own fix. I don't know if this is the same use case but I was setting up a config object for tests, and having to tear it down if one test meddled with the values (because I allowed setting values, those would persist unless I did a deep clone - but that unproxified the proxy).

```js
const baseTarget = { foo: 'baz' };
const getBaseConfig = (initialTarget = {...baseTarget}) => new Proxy(
  initialTarget,
  {
    get: (target, prop) => target[prop] ?? `proxyValueFor${prop}`,
    set: (target, prop, value) => {
      target[prop] = value;
      return true;
    },
  },
);
```

The secret sauce was spreading the simple object `baseTarget` as the default value. That way whenever it's called it get a new version of the `baseTarget`.

This doesn't give you a dynamic reset, but it should get you a way to reset the values nonetheless.